# Finding the radius of a circle given that it is tangent to both axes and contains (10, 9)

Tags: graphing-functions, geometry

A circle is tangent to both axes in the 1st quadrant of the xy-plane. If the point (10, 9) is on the circle, what is the circle radius?

[image: See the attached image. Sorry for bad drawing]

Comment: try `Solve[Norm[{10, 9} - {r ,r}] == r, r]`?

Comment: There are two such circles. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the new in M12 function [`GeometricScene`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene) for this, although it will return machine number results:

```
instance = RandomInstance @ GeometricScene[
    {c, z->{10,9}, o->{0,0}, p->{10,0}, q->{0,10}},
    {
    GeometricAssertion[{CircleThrough[{z}, c], InfiniteLine[{o,p}]}, "Tangent"],
    GeometricAssertion[{CircleThrough[{z}, c], InfiniteLine[{o,q}]}, "Tangent"]
    }
]
```

[image]

The two [`GeometricAssertion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricAssertion) statements assert that the circle through the point z is tangent to the x and y axes.

The center of the circle is located at:

```
c /. instance["Points"]
```

> {5.58359, 5.58359}

If you want to obtain the other circle, you can add a [`PlanarAngle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarAngle) predicate:

```
big = RandomInstance @ GeometricScene[
    {c,z->{10,9},o->{0,0},p->{10,0},q->{0,10}},
    {
        PlanarAngle[{c,z,o}] > 90 Degree,
        GeometricAssertion[{CircleThrough[{z}, c], InfiniteLine[{o, p}]},"Tangent"],
        GeometricAssertion[{CircleThrough[{z}, c], InfiniteLine[{o, q}]},"Tangent"]
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question that `GeometricScene` is so useful for!

Comment: Please add reference material. How did you derive this equation?

Comment: @usmanharoon I added a bit more explanation. Look up the functions in the documentation center for more details.

Answer (score 7):

The circles tangent to the two axes are  `Circle[{r, r}, r]` for some `r`. Since the unknown circle passes through `pt = {10, 9}` the distance from `pt` to the center `{r,r}` must be `r`. So,

```
pt = {10, 9};
Solve[Norm[pt - {r, r}] == r, r]
```

> {{r -> 19 - 6 Sqrt[5]}, {r -> 19 + 6 Sqrt[5]}}

Move the black dot around to see the two circles that touch the axes and pass through the black point:

```
Manipulate[sol = Solve[Norm[pt - {r, r}] == r, r]; 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Black, Dynamic[Point @ Round[pt, 1/10]], 
    Dynamic@Text[Style[ToString[Round[pt, 1/10], InputForm], 14], 
     pt, {-1.25, -1}], 
   AbsolutePointSize[5], Thick, 
   {Red, Point[{{r, 0}, {r, r}, {0, r}}], Circle[{r, r}, r], 
     Dashing[Small], Arrow[{{r, r}, {r, 0}}], Arrow[{{r, r}, {0, r}}]} /. sol[[1]], 
    {Blue, Point[{{r, 0}, {r, r}, {0, r}}], Circle[{r, r}, r], 
    Dashing[Small], Arrow[{{r, r}, {r, 0}}], Arrow[{{r, r}, {0, r}}]} /. sol[[2]]}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 16, 
  FrameTicks -> ({{{#, Pane[InputForm@#, ImageSize -> {60, 20}, 
       Alignment -> Right]} & /@ #, None},
    {{#, Pane[InputForm@#, ImageSize -> {60, 20}, 
      Alignment -> Center]} & /@ #, None}} &@
     Round[Flatten[r /. sol], 1/10]), ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0], {{pt, {10, 9}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, AppearanceElements -> None, TrackedSymbols -> {pt}]
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain it in simple terms

Comment: Is this derived theorem?
[Norm[pt - {r, r}] == r, r

Comment: @usmanharoon, `Norm[pt - {r, r}] == r` represents the statement "the point pt lies on the circle with center {r,r}" . `Norm[pt - {r, r}] ` is the distance from `pt` to the center and this distance must be equal to the radius of the circle.